# Logic distrbution property different order

Tags: logic

I have something like:

$(a \vee b) \wedge c$

Does this become $(a \vee c) \wedge (b \vee c)$?

Comment: NO; see [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement).

Comment: Just ask yourself: "Is: "I'll take pizza or pasta, and I have enough money" the same as "I'll take pizza or I have enough money, and I'll take pasta or I have enough money"?

Answer (score 1):

In Boolean algebra, the law of distributivity holds: $(a\vee b)\wedge c = (a\wedge c)\vee (b\wedge c)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
a&b&c&a \lor b&a \lor c&b \lor c&(a\lor b)\land c&(a \lor c)\land(b \lor c) \\\hline
\top&\top&\top&\top&\top&\top&\top&\top\\\hline
\top&\top&\bot&\top&\top&\top&\bot&\top\\\hline
\top&\bot&\top&\top&\top&\top&\top&\top\\\hline
\top&\bot&\bot&\top&\top&\bot&\bot&\bot\\\hline
\bot&\top&\top&\top&\top&\top&\top&\top\\\hline
\bot&\top&\bot&\top&\bot&\top&\bot&\bot\\\hline
\bot&\bot&\top&\bot&\top&\top&\bot&\top\\\hline
\bot&\bot&\bot&\bot&\bot&\bot&\bot&\bot
\end{array}$$

So $(a\lor b)\land c \equiv(a \lor c)\land(b \lor c)$ doesn't hold.

Answer (score 0):

In boolean algebra, we often denote logical AND ($\wedge$) with multiplicative notation, and logical OR ($\vee$) with additive notation, so that we may have:
$$ A(B+C) = AB + AC $$